# ggplot2: output multiple plots by looping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to output multiple plots in `ggplot2` by looping through the plot function.

Let's say I have a dataframe `points` with the coordinates for two points. I start by plotting a single point in `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
point1 <- c(1,2)
point2 <- c(2,2)

points <-as.data.frame(rbind(point1,point2))

ggplot(data = points, mapping = aes(x = points[, 1], y = points[, 2])) +
    geom_point(aes(x = points[1,1], y = points[1,2])) +
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    ylim(-3, 3) +
      theme_bw()
```

[image]

Now I would like to *loop* over the dataframe so that I can produce *two* plots, save them in a list, and print them side by side.

I have tried:

```r
library(ggplot2)
point1 <- c(1,2)
point2 <- c(2,2)

points <-as.data.frame(rbind(point1,point2))

point_plots_list <-  list()
for (i in 1:nrow(points)) {
  p <- ggplot(data = points, mapping = aes(x = points[, 1], y = points[, 2])) +
    geom_point(aes(x = points[i, 1], y = points[i, 2])) +
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    ylim(-3, 3) +
    theme_bw()
  point_plots_list[[i]] <- p
}
point_plots_list
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```r
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Question**

Why do the two plots look the same?

Comment: Besides the duplicate, your code has multiple typos or minor issues. Note that the `length()` of a `data.frame` refers to its column number, not rows. It works in your example but just because the data has as many rows as columns. Rather use `seq_len(nrow(data))`. You define the aesthetics twice in `ggplot()` and `geom_point()`. Within `ggplot()`, you call `point` not `points`. Within ggplot, you define both `data = ` and use the data in the aesthetics rather than just referring to the column names within `aes()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I have fixed `length()` and the typo with `points`. I am new to ggplot so I kind of understand where you are getting with the other issues you are raising, but I am not sure about how to fix them.

Comment: Your specific problem is well elaborated in the linked question, I think. Cannot add more to the explanation there.

Comment: Thank you, I have followed the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this answer](http://%60%60%60%20r%20library(ggplot2)%20point1%20%3C-%20c(1,2)%20point2%20%3C-%20c(2,2)%20%20points%20%3C-as.data.frame(rbind(point1,point2))%20point_plots_list%20%3C-%20vector(%27list%27,%20ncol(points))%20point_plots_list%20%3C-%20%20list()%20for%20(i%20in%201:nrow(points))%20%7B%20%20%20message(i)%20%20%20point_plots_list%5B%5Bi%5D%5D%20%3C-%20local(%7B%20%20%20%20%20i%20%3C-%20i%20%20%20p%20%3C-%20ggplot(data%20=%20points,%20mapping%20=%20aes(x%20=%20points%5B,%201%5D,%20y%20=%20points%5B,%202%5D))%20+%20%20%20%20%20geom_point(aes(x%20=%20points%5Bi,%201%5D,%20y%20=%20points%5Bi,%202%5D))%20+%20%20%20%20%20xlim(-3,%203)%20+%20%20%20%20%20ylim(-3,%203)%20+%20%20%20%20%20theme_bw()%20%20%20%7D)%20%7D%20#%3E%201%20#%3E%202%20point_plots_list%20#%3E%20%5B%5B1%5D%5D%20%60%60%60%20%20!%5B%5D(https://i.imgur.com/m60aIGP.png)%20%20%20%20%20%20#%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20#%3E%20%5B%5B2%5D%5D%20%20!%5B%5D(https://i.imgur.com/51Q9ejW.png)%20%20%3Csup%3ECreated%20on%202021-04-09%20by%20the%20%5Breprex%20package%5D(https://reprex.tidyverse.org)%20(v0.3.0)%3C/sup%3E):

```r
library(ggplot2)
point1 <- c(1,2)
point2 <- c(2,2)

points <-as.data.frame(rbind(point1,point2))
point_plots_list <- vector('list', ncol(points))
point_plots_list <-  list()
for (i in 1:nrow(points)) {
  message(i)
  point_plots_list[[i]] <- local({
    i <- i
  p <- ggplot(data = points) +
    geom_point(aes(x = points[i, 1], y = points[i, 2])) +
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    ylim(-3, 3) +
    theme_bw()
  })
}
#> 1
#> 2
point_plots_list
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

Using `lapply` instead of a `for` loop and displaying plots with `ggarrange` or `multiplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
point1 <- c(1, 2)
point2 <- c(2, 2)

points <- as.data.frame(rbind(point1, point2))

plot_data <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = data[, 1], y = data[, 2])) +
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    ylim(-3, 3) +
    theme_bw()
}
myplots <- list()
myplots <- lapply(1:nrow(points), function(i) plot_data(points[i, ]))

ggarrange(myplots[[1]], myplots[[2]], 
          
          labels = c("A", "B"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

```r
source("http://peterhaschke.com/Code/multiplot.R") #load multiplot function
multiplot(plotlist = myplots, cols = 2)
#> Loading required package: grid
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>